# How to disable publish_future_post auto add wp_options cron

Tags: database, hooks, core

My website >> database >> wp_options >> option_name >> "cron" field total size 31GB (I was so surprised @@)

After checking i see a lot of publish_future_post fields when

My website has a lot of posts scheduled for the future, we've got a feature that periodically checks if post_status = 'future' then wp_publish_post($postID)

So publish_future_post in "cron" field is not necessary

How can I block them from automatically adding to "cron" field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hook [pre_schedule_event](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_schedule_event/) to stop scheduling them, e.g.

```php
function pre_schedule_event_no_publish_future_post( $result, $event, $wp_error ) {
    if ( $event->hook === 'publish_future_post' ) {
        // Don't schedule this event
        return false;
    }
    return $result;
}
add_filter( 'pre_schedule_event', 'pre_schedule_event_no_publish_future_post', 10, 3 );
```

You could possibly remove the _future_post_hook call instead

```php
remove_action( 'future_post', '_future_post_hook', 5, 2 );
```

but I think pre_schedule_event is safer.

However I'd guess there are better ways to set this up too.

Comment: When i update post (post_type == "future")
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Too few arguments to function pre_schedule_event_no_publish_future_post(), 1 passed in /home/domain.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 289

Comment: Huh, that can't be right. Here's the two places it gets called from in core code: [cron.php line 91](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d86d26bd27cc6bee1797fa7b4cd11f62a9d7c42c/wp-includes/cron.php#L91) and [cron.php line 269](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d86d26bd27cc6bee1797fa7b4cd11f62a9d7c42c/wp-includes/cron.php#L269). You can see both pass three arguments, and the doc comment there, and the documentation I linked, all say it accepts three arguments like there are in my code.

Comment: Does your future publish feature call apply_filters('pre_schedule_event') too? I can't think where else it would be called with the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: i use add_filter instead of add_action. After remove var $wp_error, everything has turned out well

Comment: D'oh, you're right yes, should have been add_filter. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: thank you sir <3